# Unable to load profile data with Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

Resolved:   url: ('/api' +this.profilepath),

Added Vue-router to my project, unable to load profile data anymore.

---- edited ----
this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath, is not give me fullpath.
/api/ was missing ...

---

Here is the Sidebar component:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'profile' , params:{id: this.profileId}}"
 class="nav-link"
 :key="$route.fullPath"

 >Profile</router-link>
```

I am passing the profile ID to my Profile component.

Sidebar component is getting the profile ID via props:

```
 props: ['profileid'],
```

Profile component is generating axios "GET" path:

```
      data() {
    return {
        status: 'Loading ...',
        profilepath: this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath,
        profile: {
        },
      }
      },
```

My methods in Profile component to "GET" profile data:

```
       methods: {

      loadProfile(){
        console.log(this.profilepath);
        this.status = 'Loading ....';
        axios({
         url: this.profilepath,
        method: 'get'
    })


          .then(response => {
          this.profile = response.data.profile;
          this.status = ('data received ....' );
          console.log('data received ....' +this.profile);
          this.status = 'Data loaded, succesfully!';
        })
```

This was working fine, now receiving only an empty array from my Laravel backend. My Request URL is passing profile ID: `http://192.168.10.101:8000/api/profile/1`

Q) Is there something extra which I should add for axios while
using Vue-router links ?

`Error:  in render: "TypeError: _vm.profile is undefined"`

I found this from child component Userinfo which should get data via `props: ['profile']`

-- Update ---

When I do troubleshoot inside method `loadProfile()`:

```
console.log(this.profilepath);
```

It returns: `/profile/1` which is wrong!

### Problem was '/api/' was missing that's why,
I only received an empty array.

profilepath: this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath,
is not include /api/.

Comment: Post the relevant Laravel code, would make it easier to help you

Comment: api.php
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@load')->name('profile.load');

ProfileController.php
  public function load($id)
        { 
          return response()->json(Profile::find($id));
       }
This was working without vue-router.
I haven't done any changes.

Comment: Try changing `params:{...}` to `query:{...}`

Comment: my routes.js has path:"/profile/:id",
this is problem, I am missing /api/